# Is there methods for splitting a Guassian Mixture model into separate unimodal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multimodality

I want to apply an algorithm which usually works on unimodal distributions on multimodal distributions, I'm considering doing this by splitting the multimodal distributions into multiple unimodal distributions, is there any methods for doing this sort or separating/splitting?

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting"? Do you mean classifying the samples to which component they most likely belong?

Comment: Does looking at the cluster assignments of each point solve your problem? These are usually denoted by $z$; though of course that will vary.